# Как переключать музыку после её завершения

Tags: visual-basic

Я создал программу "Audio Player", думаю суть вам ясна. Мне нужно, чтобы после того как проиграл аудио файл включился другой. Я использовал стандартные формы управления `ListBox` и `AxWindowsMediaPlayer`.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как в Basic, но на C++ это выглядит так. Сами компоненты и их свойства идентичны:

```
public: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    if(axWindowsMediaPlayer1->URL != "")
    {
        int i, j;
        i = int(axWindowsMediaPlayer1->currentMedia->duration); //общая длительность
        j = int(axWindowsMediaPlayer1->Ctlcontrols->currentPosition); //текущая позиция
        if(i == j & i != 0 & j != 0)
            if(listBox1->Items->Count != 0 & listBox1->SelectedIndex != listBox1->Items->Count - 1)
            {
                listBox1->SelectedIndex = listBox1->SelectedIndex + 1;
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1->URL = listBox1->Items[listBox1->SelectedIndex]->ToString(); 
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1->Ctlcontrols->play();
            }
    }
}
```